# How to get the date from a varchar

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have an issue retrieving the data that I would like. I have a Varchar column that consist of various information. I would like to extract the date from that column only. However, I have been unsuccessful. I used the following SQL(2008) to get the data below, But I can't seem to just get the date only without the time. Obviously, the date and time are in different position. Hope you can help.

```
  SELECT substring(Data, 8, 17)
   from mastInfo


9/25/2013 12:36:5
Jul  8 2013 11:40
9/25/2013 12:43:5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT convert(date, Case When IsDate(substring(Data, 8, 17)) = 1
                          Then substring(Data, 8, 17)
                          Else NULL END) 
from mastInfo
```

Since you are starting off with a string, it is possible that it does not represent a valid date.  Using the IsDate function will return 1 when the string can be converted to a date.  Basically, this code will convert to date those values that can be converted, and will return NULL for those values that cannot be converted to a valid date.

Comment: I still get the following message: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
'. I believe I tried many ways to get this data but it seems impossible.

Comment: I apologize, but I had a close parenthesis in the wrong position.  Please try this again.

Comment: By the way, I just tested this on a SQL-2008 instance and it worked that way you wanted it to.  This code checks to see if the string can be converted before it converts it (similar to the try_convert answer that only works on SQL-2012 (and above).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2012 or newer, then you can use [Try_Convert()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx).

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/454b2/1).

Here's an example (from the above SQLFiddle):

```
Select Try_Convert(datetime, DateAsString) As DateAsDateTime
  ,DateAsString
From SomeTable
```

Here's the result:

```
DATEASDATETIME                      DATEASSTRING
September, 25 2013 12:36:05+0000    9/25/2013 12:36:5
September, 25 2013 12:43:05+0000    9/25/2013 12:43:5
July, 08 2013 11:40:00+0000         Jul 8 2013 11:40
```

Comment: I actually using SQl 2008.

Answer (score 0):

if you want convert it to date time use :

```
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, '2011-09-28 18:01:00', 120) -- to convert it to Datetime
```

if you want get time :

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), '2011-09-28 18:01:00', 100), 7))
```

if you want date part :

```
SELECT  CONVERT (DATE, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

what version of sql server?

can you try this:

SELECT convert(date, substring(Data, 8, 17))
   from mastInfo

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008. When doing so, the following error occurs, "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

Comment: Sounds like a parsing issue?  does substring(data, 8, 17) always return a date?

Answer (score 0):

First convert Varchar into DateTime and after that again convert it in varchar in desired date format like 101,102,103

Try this:

```
 select convert(varchar(50),convert(datetime,'9/25/2013 12:43:5'),101)
```